# AWS Amplify s3 Image picker status check after success uploading the image in react js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am using above tag for uploading image to s3 bucket. It does successfully uploads the image. But how do I check the callback where it is success or not? How to get the return key ? 
How to access the image after uploading through s3imagepicker?

thanks for your help